# Как копировать одно бинарное дерево в другое?

Tags: c#

Необходимо скопировать одно бинарное дерево в другое. Требований никаких нет, деревья могут быть любыми, хоть самыми простыми.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: С помощью полного обхода дерева, хоть в ширину, хоть в глубину